# Could native implementations of sleep, wait, park rely on the RTC?

Tags: java, winapi, timer, window, clock

We face some issues with real time clock (RTC) batteries. These are usually old and sometimes one of them dies... or just gets weaker. It’s not really predictable. Whether it’s triggered by a motherboard malfunction, humidity, its age or whatever, it happens. We can replace them, or change the computer but that's not the matter here.

That'd be very nice if someone knows if failure of the RTC could affect the following functions:

```
public static native void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException;
public final native void wait(long timeout) throws InterruptedException;
public native void park(boolean paramBoolean, long paramLong);
```

`park` is in `sun.misc.Unsafe`

The behavior of these functions probably depends on the operating system and hardware components but it could be... nearly anything. All I know is that it's a PC, running Windows (XP or later) and using the standard 1.6 JVM. The computer could be up to 10 years old.

I had a look at the open JDK and found that  `sleep(long millis)` is going to `WaitForMultipleObjects`. 
Absolutely no idea on `park(boolean paramBoolean, long paramLong)`  and I got lost trying to understand what’s going on with `wait(long timeout)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy test. Go to sleep for ten minutes then immediately put the clock forward an hour and see if it wakes up before the full ten minutes is done. That's probably a damn sight easier than ferreting around in the JDK internals :-)

But I've got to say it. Developers shouldn't be using ten-year-old hardware and they *especially* shouldn't be using faulty hardware.

Comment: Modifying Windows’ wall-clock also modifies the RTC. Interesting, I didn’t know that Windows had such a power ! 
Everything works fine if I play with the clock when these three functions are ‘waiting’. No side effects, apparently. But that only checks one system, it doesn’t mean that the others will behave the same way. Isn’t there a specification for the implementation of these JVM functions ?

Comment: Yes, Windows certainly does have that power. The operating system has _full_ control over the hardware. Otherwise date/time changes couldn't "stick" over power-downs.